# Cherrypy deployment - Nginx - javascript

Tags: javascript, nginx, cherrypy

I build an app on a server, with the goal of putting it behind Nginx.

the app is actually tutorial8 from the cherrypy examples (or close to it).

The nginx configuration:

```
location /Cloning/ {    
proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header    X-Originating-IP    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    HTTP_REMOTE_ADDR    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    REMOTE_ADDR         $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    CLIENT_IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8088/;
}
```

the app runs as expected (the javascript is working) when accessing under server_name:8088 (the cherrypy webserver was configured to serve the page on that page).
However, When I want to connect to it through the Nginx location, server_name/Cloning/, the javascript is not working.
What do I miss, or what should I check?
I suppose it has to do with nginx, as the app works as a charm when directly connecting to it, but it doesn't when connecting over nginx...

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

cherrypy code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import cherrypy
import os
from app import *

#app = cherrypy.tree.mount(InbioseCloning(), '/')

if __name__=='__main__':

    cherrypy.config.update({
    'server.socket_host': '0.0.0.0',
    'server.socket_port': 8088,
    'log.access_file' : './logs/log_access.txt',
    'log.screen' : True,
    'log.error_file' : './logs/log_error.txt'
    })

 conf = {
    '/': {
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.root': os.path.abspath(os.getcwd()),
        'tools.sessions.timeout':60
    },
    '/projectfetcher': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')],
    },
    '/static': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': './public'
    },
    '/data_folder': {
        'tools.staticdir.on': True,
        'tools.staticdir.dir': './data_folder'
    }
 }


webapp = CloningHomepage()
webapp.projectfetcher = ProjectFetcherService()
# webapp.lvl1creatorservice = Lvl1CreatorService()
# Run the application using CherryPy's HTTP Web Server
cherrypy.quickstart(webapp,'/', conf)
```

Comment: how do you serve static?

Comment: how do you mean? 

`location / {
# First attempt to serve request as file, then
# as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

 location / {
  # First attempt to serve request as file, then
  # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
 }

    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
`

those are the relevant parts of my nginx I guess

Comment: any cherrypy code for that?

Comment: added to initial post

Comment: What are the versions of cherrypy/python you are using? Do you run cherrypy app as a daemon? Is there any log output? (both nginx and cherrypy)

Comment: python3.4.2, cherrypy 10.1.1
I run the script in terminal (background, nohup)

Comment: Any logs? Do you prepend `/Cloning/` to your HTTP queries for static? Can you post HTTP request/response for static? you may get it from Chrome DevTools -> Networking panel